# IE Rounded Corners

Tags: internet-explorer, css, rounded-corners

I know there are a million rounded corner threads all over the web, and I have done my research and tried the PIE.htc method but no luck. For some reason it doesnt even work in IE9 according to BrowserLab.

Can anyone with IE9 be able to confirm for me? I'm on a mac.

http://heyimart.com/clients/index.html

Here is the CSS code I'm using to make the rounded corners.

```
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 120px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 120px 0px 120px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 120px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 120px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 120px 0px 120px;
border-top-right-radius: 120px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
border-radius: 0px 120px 0px 120px;

-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
behavior: url(clients/PIE.htc);
```

Thank you,
Art

Comment: IE9 supports `border-radius` natively, so it should work even without PIE. Also, why do you have both the longhand and shorthand properties defined?

Comment: I was aware that IE9 should support border-radius but it doesnt seam to work for me :/ so that's why I tried PIE aswell, to see if that could resolve it. But that still hasn't. Again I used longhand & shorthand to try more solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

URLs in `behavior` should be relative to the server root.

Change it to:

```
behavior: url(clients/PIE.htc);
```

Comment: I've changed my behavior to clients/PIE.htc but no luck according to BrowserLab.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing on ie8 (don't have ie9)…

I use this on ie8 :

```
-webkit-border-radius: 200px;
-moz-border-radius: 200px;
border-radius: 200px;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
margin:25px;
z-index: inherit;
zoom: 1; /* For IE6 */
```

Comment: Is it because I'm trying to get certain corners curved?

Answer (score 0):

use this this it's working

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style>
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
</style>
```